# How to fix "TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object"

Tags: typescript, next.js, twilio-api

How to fix "TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object"?

This is my current code:

```js
import twilio from "twilio";

const accountSid = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
const apiKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
const apiSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

const generateToken = (identity: string) =\> {
const videoGrant = new twilio.jwt.AccessToken.VideoGrant({
room: "my-room",
});
const token = new twilio.jwt.AccessToken(
accountSid, apiKey, apiSecret, { identity });

token.addGrant(videoGrant);

if (typeof token === "object" && token instanceof twilio.jwt.AccessToken) {
return token.toJwt();
}

return null;
};

export default generateToken;
```

Comment: It doesn't shows any error in tsplayground, and why do you need to check `token instanceof twilio.jwt.AccessToken`? The `token` is `new` from that class so it will always be `true`